# .htaccess 302 redirect url with php parametr to other website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can someone tell me if its gonna work correctly ?

I need to redirect 302 webpages:
http://www.mysite.domain.net/?click=url
http://www.mysite.domain.net/?url=anotherurl&version=1&reflink=base

To webpage
http:// othersite.otherdomain.com

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?click=url$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?url=program&version=1&reflink=base

    RewriteRule ^$http://othersite.otherdomain.com [L, NC]
```

Comment: I can see a definitive 301 to 302 mishap right there...

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault i need 302 redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to have `[OR]` beween to `RewriteCond` lines.
- Your syntax of `RewriteRule` is wrong.
- Space before `R` flag will cause 500.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)click=url(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)url=program&version=1&reflink=base(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://othersite.otherdomain.com/? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm :D i can't vote yet but signed as solved.